# Using Scala as a Replacement for XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt, scala

On my Scala project we have a lot of legacy XSLT and was wondering if we should convert the XSLT to Scala code.

I like XSLTs approach of applying templates to nodes, and am fine using it for purely DOM transformations, but don't think it's well suited for processing data within the XML document (hard to read and test) - I'd rather use Scala to do that.

Given Scala's built-in XML support and pattern matching I thought it may be a good replacement. Has anyone successfully converted XSLT scripts to Scala? Are there any patterns or best practices?

I'm aware of an old project to convert XSLT to Scala Source code called [XSLT2src](http://lampsvn.epfl.ch/svn-repos/scala/scalax/trunk/xslt2src/), but that has been dormant for a long time and doesn't support XSLT2.

Thanks

Comment: We had a lot of xslt which generated not xml files. Replacing the xslt with scalate + scala was pretty straight forward and is much easier to understand/develop.

Comment: I'd be inclined to suggest that if you need to do extensive processing on the data within the XML document, you should consider redesigning the layout of your XML. For example, if you've got `<data>first, second, third</data>`, this should really be `<data><item>first</item><item>second</item><item>third</item></data>`. An XML file is essentially a hierarchial database, and the 'any one field should only contain one piece of data' rule applies.

Comment: For the XSLT/XML we use, Scala's XML support is a bit lacking. We need more of XPath in there (the XML is defined by an industry standard so we can't change it). It can be hacked around by dropping back in to "normal" Scala when the \ and \\ don't do it but with a loss of readability

Answer (score 6):

It's hard to tell for sure without knowing exactly what XML you want to transform and how, but as things stand XSLT template/match are both more powerful and more readable than Scala XML pattern matching, which has a number of issues.

In particular:

- any non-trivial matching is either impossible or very hard to do
- namespaces are not supported

So you might be better off calling Saxon from Scala to perform these transformations.

Still, you might want to look at the [chapter on XML](http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/working-with-xml.html) from Programming Scala.

Finally, the prevalent opinion these days is that the built-in XML support in Scala is lacking in many ways. See e.g. [Anti-XML](http://anti-xml.org/faq.html) for a project that aims at building something better.

Answer (score 1):

[Scales Xml](http://code.google.com/p/scala-scales/) provides matching on namespaces and attributes directly but also provides a more flexible internal dsl for handling XPaths (as well as string based evaluation).

Perhaps most interesting for transformations is its ability to fold over paths, select what you want in an XPath and transform the results "[in place](http://scala-scales.googlecode.com/svn/sites/scales/scales-xml_2.9.1/0.2.1/ScalesXmlIntro.html#In-Place_Transformations)".  These transformation rules can be combined.

You could still replicate much of xslt approach with direct XPath usage in Scales and transforming/building the trees as you would in xslt.